# Select Rate based on date dow

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I am trying to select 1 of 2 rate columns from a table based on the day of the week that is being searched. I am attempting to use two tables for this query: a calendar table (table name=calendar, column name=caldates) which is strictly a list of dates where each row is a date between 2012-06-30 and 2014-05-31. I also have another table (table name=rates) that has 4 columns: start_date, end_date, weekday_rate, and weekend_rate.

```
Start_date      end_date     weekday_rate     weekend_rate
"2012-05-01"  "2012-06-30"        69              150
"2012-07-01"  "2012-08-31"        74              200
"2012-09-01"  "2012-11-14"        75              210
"2012-11-15"  "2013-01-31"        90              150
```

When a query is performed, the system needs to look up the correct rate. Right now my query looks like this:

```
SELECT  
    CASE cast(extract(dow from caldates) as int)
    WHEN '0'  then (select weekday_rate from rates)
    WHEN '1'  then (select weekday_rate from rates)
    WHEN '2'  then (select weekday_rate from rates)
    WHEN '3'  then (select weekday_rate from rates)
    WHEN '4'  then (select weekday_rate from rates)
    WHEN '5'  then (select weekend_rate from rates)
    When '6'  then (select weekend_rate from rates)
    End AS the_date_rate
FROM calendar WHERE caldates >= '2012-08-30' and  caldates <=  '2012-09-04' ;
```

When I run the query, I receive the error "ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression. "

I would like the output to display the range of dates as well as the rate associated with the date. The above example would look something like

```
caldates        the_date_rate
2012-08-30           74
2012-08-31           200
2012-09-01           210
2012-09-02           75
2012-09-03           75
2012-09-04           75
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be sufficient (also see if you really need quotes around the date-of-week value after when clause):

```
SELECT  
    CASE 
        WHEN cast(extract(dow from caldates) as int) < 6  then weekday_rate
        ELSE weekend_rate
    End AS the_date_rate
FROM 
    calendar 
WHERE 
    caldates >= '2012-08-30' and  caldates <=  '2012-09-04' ;
```

Comment: @pkracer: This answer is incorrect in multiple ways and inefficient where it isn't. You shouldn't accept it.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, the idea was to not correct or improve the logic but to unblock from the error. I certainly agree with the improvements in your answer, though. Thanks for your response.

Comment: I guess hinting at a simpler `CASE` statement was helpful, I agree. Notify me in case you fix the errors (missing JOIN, incorrect weekday assignment), and I'll remove the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

This can be largely simplified.

```
SELECT d.day
      ,CASE WHEN extract(isodow from d.day) < 6
         THEN weekday_rate
         ELSE weekend_rate
       END AS rate
FROM  (SELECT generate_series('2012-06-30'::date
                             ,'2014-05-31'::date, '1d'::interval)::date AS day
      ) d
LEFT   JOIN rates r ON d.day BETWEEN r.start_date AND r.end_date
ORDER  BY d.day
```

#### Major points

- You don't need a `calendar` table for a gapless series of dates in PostgreSQL. Use [`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html) like demonstrated instead.
- You need to join to the `rates` table. The currently accepted answer wouldn't work at all.
- I use `LEFT JOIN`, so a day without a matching rate would still be in the result with `NULL` as rate.
- The currently accepted answer treats Sunday as weekday and Friday as weekend. I don't think this is expected.
  The `CASE` statement can also be much simpler with just two cases using [`extract(isodow FROM source)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT).
- You don't have to cast the result of `extract()` to `integer`. The literal we compare to is cast to the matching type `double precision` automatically.